# How to make sure Google Analytics customVars are not too long

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

According to [Google Analytics](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html#varTypes):

> The total combined length of any custom variable name and value may
>   not exceed 64 bytes. Keep in mind that this is not equivalent to 64
>   characters. Because names and values are URI encoded when stored, some
>   characters use more than one byte. For example, = is stored as %3D
>   rather than = and uses 3 bytes rather than 1. To get a list of URI
>   encoded values, search the web for URL encoding reference.

I have two questions about that:

1. Should an encoded equal sign (=) be included in those 64 bytes?
2. I've tried to make a function that makes sure the custom name and value is not too long.
   Can it be improved? (Of course it can.)

   ```
   function truncateCustomVarAndSet(index, name, value, scope) {
       var keyValuePair, 
           encodedPair,
           lengthOK = false;
       while (!lengthOK && value.length > 0) {
           keyValuePair = name + '=' + value;
           encodedPair = encodeURIComponent(keyValuePair);
           lengthOK = encodedPair.length <= 64;
           if (!lengthOK) {
               value = value.substring(0, value.length - 1);
           }
       } 
       _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', index, name, value, scope]);        
   }
   ```

**Edit:** Now using `encodeURIComponent` instead of `encodeURI`.

**Edit 2:** @yahelc changed gaq to _qac, so I removed gaq from the argument list since it isn't needed anymore.

Comment: Someone? There was an answer for a while, but I guess the author removed it.

Comment: Well, I remember one part of that answer that helps! I should use encodeURIComponent, not encodeURI. I'll update my question.

Comment: Another thing in the answer that disappeared: it stated that the equal sign should be included in the 64 bytes, thus making only 61 bytes available.

Comment: My answer was fatally flawed, so I removed it. I'm re-thinking what the right approach here is, but, switching to `encodeURIComponent` was the only seemingly correct insight I had :)

Comment: And a few others, as noted :) Thanks!

Comment: According to http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/community/gajs_changelog.html#release-2012-01 the limit has been increased to 128 characters. Interestingly, the wording is "character" rather than "byte" from previous documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested pushing custom variables of exactly 64 characters combined, and it looks like 64 is ONLY the encoded bytes of the key and the value, not of any connecting characters.

You should use `encodeURIComponent`, because than [`encodeURI` does not encode `&`, `+`, and `=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI).

Also, don't forget the underscore in front of `_gaq`. `_gaq` *needs* to be a global variable, so, no need to pass it through as a parameter.

It looks like your general approach works, and avoids the issue of mistakenly cropping the string in the middle of an encoded character (as my previous approach mistakenly did.)

Here's a slimmed down version of your code (cuts ~220 chars):

```
function truncateCustomVarAndSet(index, name, value, scope) {
    while (value.length && encodeURIComponent(name + value).length > 64) {
            value = value.substring(0, value.length-1);
    } 
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', index, name, value, scope]);        
}
```

Tested with this:

```
truncateCustomVarAndSet(3,"34567890345678903=1=1=456789034567895678904567890","211222$#!#11221122112122112eeeqeqqeqefo1op2k1po12kop21pok2p1o",1)
_gaq.push(["_trackPageview"]);
```

And that records as:

> **Custom Var 3** 
>   
>   **label**: '34567890345678903=1=1=456789034567895678904567890' 
>   
>   **value**: '211222$'
>   
>   **scope**: '1'

Comment: I intentionally did not do it your way, because I was afraid substringing the encoded value might cut it in the middle of an encoded character, thus rendering it impossible to decode. Are you saying that can not happen?

Comment: I'll use `encodeURIComponent`, thanks! On substr vs substring, can you elaborate (as I couldn't find anything specific on this in a reasonable googling)?

Comment: Here's an example on the problem I think exists with your approach: If I set name to `"fooz"` and value to `"a%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"` Firefox/Firebug tells me: "URIError: malformed URI sequence"

Comment: My previous comments about a problem in the code are now void, since @yahelc has updated the answer.

Comment: And I salute your much simpler solution. Less is more.

Answer (score 1):

1. from the description, it doesn't seem like the "=" is meant to be counted as part of the set, only if the key or value had an equals.
2. I've reduced your function a bit.

```
function truncateCustomVarAndSet(index, name, value, scope) {
    var n = encodeURIComponent(name)
        ,v = encodeURIComponent(value)
    for(;(n + v).length > 64; v=encodeURIComponent(value=value.substr(1-value.length)));
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', index, name, value, scope]);        
}
```

Comment: Your solution is much simpler than mine, and so is @yahelc's. +1 to both.